# Book Capitalization Class Error

Tags: ruby, string, class, rspec

I'm teaching myself how to code and can't seem to understand how the inputted title is being called by this class. Where does the argument go to first? The attr_accessor or the def title  capital_it(@title)  end?

```
class Book

    attr_accessor :title

    def title
        capital_it(@title)
    end

    def capital_it(title)
        word_arr = @title.capitalize.split(" ")
        word_arr.map do |word|
            word.capitalize! unless little_words.include?(word)
            end
        word_arr.join(" ")
    end

    def little_words
        ["the", "a", "an", "and", "in", "of"]
    end

end
```

Comment: Error messages are there to guide you. In your `capital_it` method, your `map` `do` is missing an `end`.

Comment: According to your `initialize` method, when you create a new book with `Book.new` you have to pass an argument i.e. `@book = Book.new('a title')`.

Comment: I don't seem to understand how arguments are passed through classes and what function each method serves based on how it is set up with instance variables.
I got the spec to work but I had to do "def initializer" without argument and in the body pass the instance variable through the method like this: capital_it(@title).

Comment: Might be worth following a tutorial of some sort, there are quite a few concepts to understand. This link http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/writing_classes/initializers.html may help in the meantime to understand `initialize`.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help sagarpandya82! It finally passed the checks and I now see that I don't understand how attr_accessors and initializer methods work exactly and/or how the arguments are inputted into the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where does the argument go to first? The `attr_accessor` or the `def title` ... ?

`attr_accessor :title` defines two methods for you: `title` (the "reader") and `title=` (the "writer"). When you do `def title` after `attr_accessor`, you replace the `title` method entirely with your new method.

In other words, the method generated by `attr_accessor` is never called, because you've overwritten it with your own method.

Since you're writing your own "reader" method, you should just use `attr_writer`:

```
class Book
  attr_writer :title

  def title
    capital_it(@title)
  end

  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have an issue in your `def capital_it(title)` method.

1. `.map` method will return a new array which you didn't assign to anything. If you want to reassign it to local variable `word_arr` use `.map!` instead.
2. You should probably rewrite condition `word.capitalize! unless little_words.include?(word)` to this `little_words.include?(word) ? word : word.capitalize`

P.S. In your case it works because you use `capitalize!` on each string of element but the style of writing like that isn't good.

So I'd recommend you to write your class like this one:

```
class Book
  SKIP = %w(the a an and in of)

  attr_writer :title

  def initialize(title)
    @title = title
  end

  def title
    capital(@title)
  end

  private

  def capital(title)
    array = @title.split(/\s+/)
    array.map! do |word|
      SKIP.include?(word) ? word: word.capitalize
    end
    array.join(" ")
  end
end
```

Comment: what is the point of the "private" I've seen it on many solutions yet I can't find the reasoning behind why its used. I thought it was meant for hiding code from users of your websites or programs

Comment: @stringathing It's about [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))